# A scrollbar in form for particular fields

Tags: javascript, html, css, scrollbar, webix

is there a way to display the vertical scrollbar for the particular fields within Webix ui.form? The point is that the `scroll:true` shows the scroll for the entire form, so I wonder whether it's possible to show the scrollbar only for the inputs (and *not* for buttons)?

[**Here**](http://webix.com/snippet/7ae30fc9)'s the most obvious, but unsatisfying solution:

```
webix.ui({
  view:"form", 
  id:"initial",
  scroll:true,
  width:300,
  elements:[
    { view:"text", label:"Login"},
    . . .
    { margin:5, cols:[
      { view:"button", value:"Login" , type:"form" },
      { view:"button", value:"Cancel" }
    ]}
  ]
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use scrollView to achieve desired result.

```
webix.ui({
  view:"form", 
  id:"initial",
  width:300,
  elements:[
    { 
      view:"scrollview", 
      height:200, 
      body: {
        rows: [
          { view:"text", label:"Field"},
          { view:"text", label:"Field"},
          { view:"text", label:"Field"},
          { view:"text", label:"Field"},
          { view:"text", label:"Field"},
          { view:"text", label:"Field"},
          { view:"text", label:"Field"},
          { view:"text", label:"Field"},
          { view:"text", label:"Field"},
          { view:"text", label:"Field"},
          { view:"text", label:"Field"}
        ]           
        }
    },

    { margin:5, cols:[
      { view:"button", value:"Login" , type:"form" },
      { view:"button", value:"Cancel" }
    ]}
  ]
});
```

please see [this](http://docs.webix.com/api__refs__ui.scrollview.html) for more info.